# React Native Keyboard returnkey change

Tags: react-native

I want to change the returnKey text of my react native app screen to a text. The default is the enter key. How can I change the text of the return key and execute a function when clicks on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change the value of the return button, have a look at the docs on `TextInput`s [`returnKeyLabel`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeylabel) (Android Only) or [`returnKeyType`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype).

To capture the return event, add the [`onSubmitEditing` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onsubmitediting) to the `TextInput`.

Comment: Thanks Jordan for the answer